# Is there a better way to handle user sessions in Flutter, than using "flutter_session" or "local_storage", or is impossible to handle that on mobile?

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart, session, mobile

Do we have to handle them from the back-end only? Because those two libraries to me they act as storage, they not doing what I am expecting.

Do I have to send a request to the back-end every time I want to resume my app state to renew the token, if the app was on foreground for some period of time?

Comment: Have you looked at the SharedPreferences ?

Comment: SharedPreference doesn't work well on IOS. What do you usually use? @BabC

Comment: SharedPreferences =/
But did you look at https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: what do you use on he background?? if its firebase then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel by far the best way to handle sessions in flutter is by using Shared Preferences
Link to the package:
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

It can be used to create multiple tokens or flag which can be said as cookie equivalents of a website.

I think you will figure out the working by looking at the documentation or the example, it is fairly simple

Answer (score 0):

For more sensitive data you may be better to use [Secure Storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) which will ensure that the data is encrypted. Shared preferences stores the data that is not encrypted